# Warning: Updating a style property during rerender (borderColor) when a conflicting property is set (border) can lead to styling bugs

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the following error

Warning: Updating a style property during rerender (borderColor) when a conflicting property is set (border) can lead to styling bugs. To avoid this, don't mix shorthand and non-shorthand properties for the same value; instead, replace the shorthand with separate values.
in div (created by Dropdown)
in div (created by Dropdown)
in Dropdown (created by MultiSelect)
in div (created by MultiSelect)

https://github.com/Khan/react-multi-select

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code into your question? Links change and disappear so it's best to copy code into questions so the question + answer will remain relevant even if the link goes away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just telling you to replace the `border` style property with the complete set of property to style borders, that is `borderWidth`, `borderStyle`, `borderColor`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the component react multiselect and not with my project. The issue is with the component css property.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the style that comes with the object keys and assign it as a direct value if there is one.